# React imported css not available

Tags: css, reactjs, webpacker

I'm trying to implement [react-component/time-picker](https://github.com/react-component/time-picker) in a component of mine.

The imports seem to "work", but the component is not getting the styles it needs.

```
import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker'
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css'
```

I've dug around in the source files and found the message below that the css was "**removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin**". I don't know if this is normal or the cause of my problems.

```
/*!******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/rc-time-picker/assets/index.css ***!
  \******************************************************/
/*! dynamic exports provided */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

I'm not a react expert, and the React app was set up via Rails / Webpacker by someone who has left the company.

I've found the the css is getting compiled fine into **public/bundle-c9134289a37e525df9bab3bda8e77e4f.css** without error.

So, my issue is that the CSS doesn't seem to be available on my page. I don't understand where imported CSS is supposed to go and how is it controlled? But, it seems like this CSS isn't going there.

Am I missing something obvious?

***Edit 1:***

**config/webpack/loaders/less.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader']
  })
}
```

**config/webpack/environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const less = require('./loaders/less')

environment.loaders.append('less', less)
module.exports = environment
```

Comment: `extract-text-webpack-plugin` removes the CSS so that it can be minified and added to a separate minified CSS file. Check this link: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/434

Comment: @GauravPunjabi But what file? And do I need to manually load it in the page?

Comment: `extract-text-webpack-plugins` is depreciated. Use mini-css-extract-plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin.

Comment: Its an additional plugin which you should add to webpack config.

Comment: @pixelearth Can you show your `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: @GauravPunjabi added some files. I don't have that exact file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css'
```

To your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file

Docs: [rails/webpacker CSS, Sass, SCSS](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md#add-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('yourfile.min.css');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: extractCSS.extract({
    use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader']
  })
}
```

Comment: This did not create a file named yourfile.min.css

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then. That's how I use it in my setup and it creates a file in my `dist` folder.